# Convert Oracle SQL query to PySpark SQL, with comma separated tables in FROM clause (joins)

Tags: oracle, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying convert the following Oracle SQL query to PySpark format in its exact form:

```
SELECT    ' '                              location_code
           ,TO_CHAR(a.invoice_id)                            invoice_id
           ,a.invoice_num                                    invoice_number
           ,a.invoice_date               invoice_date
           /*
           ,TO_CHAR( NVL(b.amount,0)
                    ,'999999999999999.99'
                   )                                         invoice_amount
           */
           ,case
                when (a.Cancelled_Date is null) then TO_CHAR(NVL(b.amount,0),'999999999999999.99')
                else '0'
           end as invoice_amount
           ,NVL(a.discount_amount_taken,0)                   discount_amount_taken
           ,' '                                              check_number
           ,NULL                                             check_date
           ,a.source                                         invoice_record_type
           ,b.description                                    invoice_description
           ,a.attribute1                                     invoice_misc1
           ,  TO_CHAR(a.vendor_id)
            ||'-'
            ||TO_CHAR(a.vendor_site_id)                      vendor_id
           ,i.vendor_name                                    vendor_name
           ,b.vat_code                                       sales_tax_jurisdiction
           ,a.invoice_currency_code                          currency_code
           ,a.invoice_type_lookup_code                       invoice_type
           ,a.payment_method_lookup_code                     check_type
           ,a.creation_date                                  ap_keyed_date
           ,'O'                                              data_source
           ,k.due_date                                       sched_payment_date
           ,a.invoice_received_date                          invoice_received_date
           ,m.name                                           payment_terms
           ,' '                                              total_amount_dispersed
           ,a.attribute2                                     invoice_misc2
           ,' '                                              bank_account_number
           ,TO_CHAR(a.exchange_rate,'999.999999999999999')   exchange_rate
           ,' '                                              on_hold_status
           ,' '                                              misc_1099_box
           ,' '                                              misc_1099_exempt_amount
           ,' '                                              misc_1099_tax_withheld
           ,a.attribute3                                     invoice_misc3
           ,a.attribute4                                     invoice_misc4
           ,NVL( a.voucher_num
                ,TO_CHAR(a.doc_sequence_value)
               )                                             voucher_number
           ,b.period_name                                    fiscal_period
           ,' '                                              gl_project_id
           ,' '                                              gl_misc1
           ,' '                                              gl_misc2
           ,b.dist_code_combination_id                   
           ,b.po_distribution_id                           
           ,a.batch_id                                    
           ,b.line_type_lookup_code          
           ,b.set_of_books_id                        
           ,b.accounting_date                         
           ,NVL(b.amount,0)                    inv_dist_amt 
           ,a.payment_status_flag                           
           ,a.cancelled_amount                 inv_cancel_amt 
           ,a.invoice_amount                   inv_hdr_amount
           ,a.created_by                                      
           ,a.org_id                                         
           ,a.last_updated_by                               
           ,a.cancelled_date                    
           ,' '                                check_status   
           ,TO_NUMBER(NULL)                    check_id     
           ,TRUNC(a.creation_date)             rate_date  
           ,NULL                               rate_date2    
           ,NVL(b.amount,0) / DECODE( NVL( a.invoice_amount,0)
                                          ,0 ,1
                                          ,NVL(a.invoice_amount,0)
                                         )     inv_dist_percent 
           ,NULL                               payment_num
           ,b.tax_code_id                                   
           ,null                               cleared_date  
           ,b.rcv_transaction_id               rcv_transaction_id 
       ,aila.model_number                  part_number
       ,aila.description                   part_description
       ,aila.unit_meas_lookup_code         unit_of_measure
       ,aila.quantity_invoiced             invoice_quantity
       ,to_char(aila.unit_price, '999999999999999.99')    unit_price                                       
       ,b.summary_tax_line_id              summary_tax_line_id
       ,assa.vendor_site_code || '-' || nvl(assa.vendor_site_code_alt,'')                                       misc5   
           ,NULL                                                                                                    void_date 
           ,papf.full_name                                                                                          approver  
  FROM  ap_invoices_all                a
       ,ap_invoice_distributions_all   b
       ,ap_suppliers                   i
       ,ap_supplier_sites_all          assa  
       ,ap_payment_schedules_all       k
       ,ap_terms_tl                    m    
       ,ap_invoice_lines_all           aila 
       ,per_all_people_f               papf 
 WHERE  a.invoice_id          = b.invoice_id
   AND  a.invoice_id          = k.invoice_id(+)
   AND  i.vendor_id           = a.vendor_id
   and  a.vendor_site_id      = assa.vendor_site_id 
   AND  m.term_id             = a.terms_id
   AND  b.invoice_id          = aila.invoice_id
   AND  b.invoice_line_number = aila.line_number
   AND  a.requester_id         = papf.person_id (+)             
   AND  trunc(a.last_update_date) between papf.effective_start_date  (+) and papf.effective_end_date (+)  
   AND  k.payment_num = 1
   AND  (a.cancelled_date is NULL)
   AND  a.payment_status_flag BETWEEN 'N' AND 'P'
order by a.invoice_id, b.invoice_distribution_id;
```

Here the joins are in the form of comma separated tables and Oracle (+) operator which means LEFT OUTER JOIN.

This is the PySpark SQL format I generated reading various docs and articles:

```
SELECT     " "                            location_code
           ,a.invoice_id                          invoice_id
           ,a.invoice_num                                    invoice_number
           ,a.invoice_date               invoice_date
           ,case
                when (ISNULL(a.Cancelled_Date)) then NVL(b.amount,0)
                else '0'
           end as invoice_amount
           ,NVL(a.discount_amount_taken,0)                   discount_amount_taken
           ," "                                              check_number
           ," "                                             check_date
           ,a.source                                         invoice_record_type
           ,b.description                                    invoice_description
           ,a.attribute1                                     invoice_misc1
           , concat(STRING(a.vendor_id)
            ,"-"
            ,STRING(a.vendor_site_id))                       vendor_id
           ,i.vendor_name                                    vendor_name
           ,b.vat_code                                       sales_tax_jurisdiction
           ,a.invoice_currency_code                          currency_code
           ,a.invoice_type_lookup_code                       invoice_type
           ,a.payment_method_lookup_code                     check_type
           ,a.creation_date                                  ap_keyed_date
           ,"O"                                              data_source
           ,k.due_date                                       sched_payment_date
           ,a.invoice_received_date                          invoice_received_date
           ,m.name                                           payment_terms
           ," "                                              total_amount_dispersed
           ,a.attribute2                                     invoice_misc2
           ," "                                              bank_account_number
           ,a.exchange_rate   exchange_rate
           ," "                                              on_hold_status
           ," "                                              misc_1099_box
           ," "                                              misc_1099_exempt_amount
           ," "                                              misc_1099_tax_withheld
           ,a.attribute3                                     invoice_misc3
           ,a.attribute4                                     invoice_misc4
           ,NVL( a.voucher_num
                ,a.doc_sequence_value
               )                                             voucher_number
           ,b.period_name                                    fiscal_period
           ," "                                              gl_project_id
           ," "                                              gl_misc1
           ," "                                              gl_misc2
           ,b.dist_code_combination_id                   
           ,b.po_distribution_id                           
           ,a.batch_id                                    
           ,b.line_type_lookup_code          
           ,b.set_of_books_id                        
           ,b.accounting_date                         
           ,NVL(b.amount,0)                    inv_dist_amt 
           ,a.payment_status_flag                           
           ,a.cancelled_amount                 inv_cancel_amt 
           ,a.invoice_amount                   inv_hdr_amount
           ,a.created_by                                      
           ,a.org_id                                         
           ,a.last_updated_by                               
           ,a.cancelled_date                    
           ," "                                check_status   
           ," "                    check_id     
           ,DATE_TRUNC("DAY", a.creation_date)             rate_date  
           ," "                               rate_date2    
           ,NVL(b.amount,0) / ( CASE WHEN NVL( a.invoice_amount,0) == 0 THEN 1
                                ELSE  NVL( a.invoice_amount,0)
                                END )     inv_dist_percent 
           ," "                               payment_num
           ,b.tax_code_id                                   
           ," "                               cleared_date  
           ,b.rcv_transaction_id               rcv_transaction_id 
       ,aila.model_number                  part_number
       ,aila.description                   part_description
       ,aila.unit_meas_lookup_code         unit_of_measure
       ,aila.quantity_invoiced             invoice_quantity
       ,aila.unit_price    unit_price                                       
       ,b.summary_tax_line_id              summary_tax_line_id
       ,concat(STRING(assa.vendor_site_code), "-", STRING(nvl(assa.vendor_site_code_alt,"")))                      misc5   
           ," "                                                                                                    void_date 
           ,papf.full_name                                                                                          approver  
  FROM  ap_invoices_all                a
        JOIN ap_invoice_distributions_all   b   ON   a.invoice_id          = b.invoice_id
        JOIN ap_supplier_sites_all          assa    ON   a.vendor_site_id      = assa.vendor_site_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ap_payment_schedules_all k   ON   a.invoice_id  = k.invoice_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN per_all_people_f papf   ON   a.requester_id  = papf.person_id
        JOIN ap_terms_tl                    m    ON   m.term_id             = a.terms_id
        JOIN ap_suppliers                   i    ON   i.vendor_id           = a.vendor_id
        JOIN ap_invoice_lines_all           aila ON b.invoice_id          = aila.invoice_id AND b.invoice_line_number = aila.line_number
 WHERE    k.payment_num = 1
   AND  ISNULL(a.Cancelled_Date)
   AND  a.payment_status_flag BETWEEN 'N' AND 'P'           
   AND  DATE_TRUNC("DAY", a.last_update_date) between papf.effective_start_date  and papf.effective_end_date   
order by a.invoice_id, b.invoice_distribution_id;
```

Changes made:

1. Oracle (+) operator converted to corresponding LEFT OUTER JOIN statement.
2. Equal constraints in WHERE clauses have been put in ON constraints in JOIN statements.
3. Oracle TRUNC("date with timestamp") function converted to PySpark DATE_TRUNC("DAY", "date with timestamp")
4. NULL fields have been replaced with " ".
5. Oracle DECODE function converted to PySpark CASE WHEN.

But still my PySpark SQL query does not generate any data (blank output) for a given date_time, even though the Oracle query generates data.
Also, I am not getting how to convert the statement TO_CHAR(a.exchange_rate,'999.999999999999999') to appropriate format in PySpark SQL.

Could anyone please help me in converting the joins in PySpark format properly, and why my PySpark query is not able to generate any data, and also convert TO_CHAR(a.exchange_rate,'999.999999999999999') to appropriate format in PySpark SQL?

Thanks,
Soubhik

Comment: Don't do it all at once; go step-by-step. First select values from only one table and check whether it works. If YES (it should ...), then add the second table into the FROM clause, properly join it to the first table and test query again. If it works, move on to the third table, and so forth. Don't move on if - at any step - you have error(s) or query doesn't return data it should!

Comment: Thanks @Littlefoot, I tried taking the tables one by one, and it is generating data but unable to understand how to combine the tables in the FROM statement. You see the table `ap_invoices_all                a` is used multiple times in the FROM clause in Oracle query, and I have to join with other tables too, is where I am getting confused